# What's the point of facebook.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand the point of this domain existing. I guess it's not hurting anything but it certainly doesn't help anything. It seems like if we were to have tag-linking domains, we would have one for the top tags like [java.stackoverflow.com](http://java.stackoverflow.com) or [csharp.stackoverflow.com](http://csharp.stackoverflow.com). But those don't exist. So what is the point of [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: [`facebook.stackoverflow.com`](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) redirects to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*`.

Comment: @Cupcake I know but why facebook? Why not java or c#?

Comment: It's an artifact of the middle ages, when we partnered with Facebook.  It didn't work out, but we still have the artifact... We're sentimental that way.

Comment: I don't know the full history, but it's probably a legacy link left over from when Facebook had a more active support partnership with Stack Overflow.

Comment: Take a look at [Is it time to re-evaluate the Facebook-Stack Overflow partnership?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership)

Comment: For context: ["Announcing facebook.stackoverflow.com"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)

Comment: Coming soon: Facebook Overflow!

Comment: stackbook.faceoverflow.com

Comment: Well, there is the [truck-load-of-money myth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103977/how-are-new-stack-overflow-mini-sites-created/103992#103992)...

Comment: Would someone take all these comments and write an answer please

Comment: [***This facebook.SO business didn't get out of control. It didn't get out of control and we were lucky to live through it.***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1228/wont)

Comment: bookstack.overface.com *...ouch*

Comment: Tempted to downvote for making us *relive the horror*.

Comment: the horror...the horror...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

facebook.stackoverflow.com redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*

As Robert Harvey wrote:

> It's an artifact of the middle ages, when we partnered with Facebook. It didn't work out, but we still have the artifact...

It's a legacy link left over from when Facebook had a more active support partnership with Stack Overflow.

Take a look at [Is it time to re-evaluate the Facebook-Stack Overflow partnership?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership)

For context: ["Announcing facebook.stackoverflow.com"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)

See the following answer for [How are new Stack Overflow mini-sites created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103977/how-are-new-stack-overflow-mini-sites-created/103992#103992) to find out about the what has been referred to as "truck-load-of-money myth"

Comment: did you just copied the comments of the question as an answer? is it a good practice?

Comment: @Unicornist It _does_ answer the question, and they've posted it as a community wiki which gives nothing back to the them (points-wise). _I_ think it's fine.

Comment: @Whymarrh the MSO rep is hidden by default (MSO always displays the reputation from main), I'm unsure whether the hidden reputation has any actual value. And you still get badges from posting CWs, which is pretty much the only visible thing you can earn by garnering upvotes on meta.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Noted. I was unaware.

Comment: @Unicornist - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216377/answering-in-comments

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: it's not hidden; it doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Wooble well, the votes are registered just like on main, and a reputation could be easily calculated from them. "Existence" is a bit subjective here.

Answer (score 8):

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ [was launched with great excitement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/) back in August 24<sup>th</sup> 2011.

> So when the largest social developer platform in the world came to us and said they wanted to partner with us, we were all ears.  And because of that partnership, we are proud to announce that http://facebook.stackoverflow.com is launching today as the new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers

First signs of trouble were spotted no more than [6 months later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership).

[Desperate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121688/152859) [attempts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128344/152859) were made to keep it alive, but the partnership dwindled away slowly and silently, like a candle running out of wax. Today it exists, but as far as I can tell not a single Facebook dev/employee is even looking in questions on Stack Overflow as part of his job.

Comment: It doesn't really "exist" in the same sense as it used to: the filtered mini-site functionality is gone (and has never been revived for other purposes).

Comment: I'm sure FB employees are looking in questions on SO...just for answers, instead of to post answers!