# Suggestions: another version of Teams: public Q&A for proprietary software paid for by the owners

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams

Like an Azure Q&A. And another for AWS. If they want to pay that is. An open platform that closed platforms can buy tenants in for their product families. So should be able to have a hierarchy.

A few of my use cases:

1. Trying to find documentation for [AzCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), how to delete finds on MS storage - Q&A would help a lot
2. With AWS as well, I have earlier had difficulty finding out how to get  function applications to work

Comment: While this is an interesting idea I can't see someone who can offload support to Stack Overflow for free paying for the same thing.

Comment: Companies like Google already direct people to Stack Overflow in their official docs. Why would they want to start paying for what they do for free?

Comment: Who exactly is going to pay for something they can do for a third of the costs?  Azure and Microsoft can document their software for a fraction of what it Teams would cost (at the size they would require).  Those looking for answers certainly will not pay for something they can get for free via Stack Exchange.

Comment: There was sort of similar thing before [with Facebook](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/24/facebook-stackoverflow/). It [brought up some questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264156/whats-the-point-of-facebook-stackoverflow-com) and then it ultimately failed. IIRC the biggest problem was Facebook themselves not participating but, really, it was ultimately a matter of time.

Comment: @tgkprog this is a great idea. as someone who has worked on the product the last 3.5 years, we have received a ton of inbound interest in giving devs a better way to interface with an organizations own technical team. for example, on how to use an api, an sdk, etc. - It's something we're exploring building, but are in the very early stages of seeing what it could look like and do not have any specifics on dates or if we'll be able to get to it yet. Nonetheless, thank you for expressing that it would be helpful for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correct! We are thinking about it; we know it is a problem, and we are thinking of ways to solve this, but it's not going to be resolved in the near term. We'll probably revisit this request sometime next year.